# Is this vent pipe and p-trap configuration to code?

Tags: plumbing, water-heater

I'm removing a stackable washer/dryer and installing a vanity sink for my daughters art studio.  All the lines are in place, hot & cold water lines and vent pipe (washer's waste water pipe), however as I opened the wall to relocate the valves and tap into the washer's vent line, I came across the following.

[image: Current Install & Planned Upgrade]

As you can see in the sketch, "Current" shows an existing p-trap from the washer's vent line, in the wall.  I've read various "not a good idea to have two p-traps on the same line" scenarios due to potential lack of pressure and possible backwash, etc.

Any how, what I'd like to do, and know if it's within code, "Upgrade" is add a vent line for the vanity on the existing vent pipe, just above the washer's vent line?

---

A bit off topic but... I also noticed that there's only one shut-off valve (hot water line) on the water heater, and nothing for the cold one; is this normal?  How do you go about turning the cold water off to run new lines?

[image: Water-Heater Tank]

Comment: There's no sketch in your post. To turn off the cold, you turn off all of the water. The IPC calls for a shutoff valve (technically a "full open valve") where the water first enters the structure, and I assume the UPC has a similar requirement. That's the valve to turn off. Trace the cold water feeding your hot water tank back toward the street and you'll eventually find it inside the house somewhere. Unless your install doesn't meet code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In some (normally) warmer places the shutoff and meter (if public water) may be outside the house. I live in a place where that would be insane due to freezing. [Edit] your post and use the "sun and mountains" icon above the edit box to insert your picture. LEAVE THE CODE IT INSERTS ALONE. Look below the edit box for the preview of how it will post. On many computers you can also drag and drop an image.

Comment: What size is the washer drain pipe? If to current codes (2") an additional P-trap is unlikely to be a problem.

Comment: @popham -Can't upload image, keep getting an error message.  This is a rental, not a home. I've traced both the hot and the cold water lines and they lead me to a closet where the water heater/tank is located.  out of this water heater, only the hot water has an On/Off valve and I need to turn them both Off so I can move/extend the water lines to feed the vanity sink.

Comment: @Ecnerwal -My concern is that if there where to be a blockage a double p-trap could become an issue, the original p-trap is buried in the wall, and yes the pipe is 2".  I did try the drag and drop image suggestion, it did not work, same error message.

Comment: In most areas, plumbing changes are not a thing rental tenants should be doing on their own... Homeowners are generally cut more slack.

Comment: @Ecnerwal -yes, thank you, I'm aware of that, and so is the homeowner

Comment: You've traced the cold all the way to a point where it enters a slab of concrete or punches through an exterior wall? Rental units under the IPC (are you in the US?) and probably the UPC are supposed to each have a shutoff. A two family dwelling can be an exception, though.

Comment: @popham -yes, I'm in NC. I hear what you're saying; trace the line coming into the actual structure; no, I haven't done that... yet.  That said, why would a water heater only have a shut-off valve for the hot water line and not the cold water line?

Comment: Because it's not plumbed with one. You need a shutoff valve per IPC 503. Doesn't mean that whoever plumbed the thing in actually followed the rule.

Comment: The purpose of the interior shutoff is to facilitate repairs probably. I would be really annoyed with the plumber if I had a problem between the location where the plumbing enters and his shutoff valve. Best to put it as close as possible to that entry location.

Comment: Even if I locate the main water line coming into the structure and shut it off, there's still water in the water heater tank.  I would still need a shut-off valve on the actual water lines (hot & cold) coming off the tank to prevent a small flood.  As I already mentioned, the hot water line coming off the water heater tank has a shut-off valve, but not the cold water line.  Is there a work-around for this, is there a way to add a shut-off valve to the cold water line, without creating a small lake in the closet?

Comment: @Jose, shut off the water and then open faucets to flush the unpressurized water from the pipes down drains. Some water is going to spill on the floor, though. The hot water lines require pressure from the cold water to operate, so just shutting the main valve is sufficient.

Comment: If you can't get the images uploaded here, go to imgur.com and upload them there, then share the links here, either directly in your question or down here in the comments. Someone will embed them for you.

Comment: @FreeMan -thank you for that

Comment: I think you meant two P-traps on the same drain.  The upgrade is two drains and each drain requires it's own P-trap before the main drain/vent.  If removing the washer, then can cap that drain line.  P-traps require water added every so often to not dry out.

Comment: What diameter is your washer standpipe and p-trap? How tall is your standpipe measured from the top of the glued joint at its base? What diameter is the vent pipe?

Comment: The vent pipe is the pipe that goes all the way up through the ceiling.

Answer (score 1):

Your photo appears to show the shutoff at the water heater on the COLD line. It's quite normal to have only one valve at the W.H. on the cold line, because the hot water piping is necessarily downstream of that valve. You can always use the main shutoff on the water service where it enters your building to shut off all piping.

Your schematic of the "UPGRADE" drain piping looks fine, as long as the washer drain is sized 2", and the section of wet vent between the washer santee and the sink santee is sized 2" (one size greater than normally required)

Comment: If that drawing is to scale, then the standpipe looks shorter than 18".

Comment: @crip659's comment is correct about how the old washer's p-trap is going to go dry and then become a problem.

Comment: @popham -No, the sketch is not to scale, it simply shows what the plan is, the before and after.

Comment: @crip659 -I originally thought of just connecting to the washer's vent line but I read where multiple p-traps on the same line could create a future problem, thus a separate line for the sink; the Upgrade.  I want to leave the washer hook up as it stands, if she later changes her mind, less work later on.  Your comment... If removing the washer, then can cap that drain line... is this "you can cap" or "you can't cap.  You continue to say that  "P-traps require water added every so often to not dry out."  Why should I be concerned with the p-trap drying out?

Comment: @popham -Yes, I get that.  This is why I'm going to cap the washer's vent line.  If this is the concern for the p-trap drying out, wont capping the washer's vent line prevent this from happening or is there more to the story?  Also, in answer to your previous question [photo of pipes in the wall](https://i.imgur.com/xEhaGZm.jpg) the vent pipe has 2" marked on its surface; but to be honest, I haven't measured them.  since the initial install was done in the rough, I'm assuming it passed inspection.